# Google Sheets - COUNT RECORDS INSERTED PER DAY BY EMPLOYEE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a google form that creates several daily records (lines in my spreadsheet) that has a timestamp field.  These records are inputed by employees identified by their email.

I need to count the number of records inserted by each employee each day.

Ruth created 30 entries on April 7th, 2020.

Count records by ruth, on april 7th 2020.

Thanks

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`countifs`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) function.

`=countifs(nameColumn,"=desiredName",dateColumn,"="&DATE(2020,4,7))`

Comment: Please include more details to your question if you want a more detailed answer.